# Proving the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

> $\mathbf{Riemann-Lebesgue \ Lemma \ in \ L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}$. Suppose that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $\hat{f}(k) \rightarrow 0$ as $|k| \rightarrow \infty$.

I cannot understand any of the proofs online, especially this one which seems close to what I would like to prove. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~soshniko/201c/hw5sol.pdf. I think a point of particular problems for me is which denseness properties to use as I am not that familiar with these.

If possible can it be done without using compact support as I not seen this concept much? I would as simple a proof as possible.

EDIT: I have checked in the textbook uc davis were using and there is no riemann lebesgue lemma for smoothly compacted functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the density of smooth compactly supported functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Namely, if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then there is a sequence of smooth compactly supported functions $f_n$ such that $\|f-f_n\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. This is exactly what lines 6-7 of the solution say.

Comment: The solution also uses a Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma for smooth compactly supported functions? Where is the proof of this?

Comment: @1234 : Integration by parts is the proof for compactly supported smooth functions.

Comment: @T.A.E. Sorry I do not understand what you mean by that

Comment: @1234 : Did you try to integrate by parts? Look at the expression after you do. You'll see it.